# Hide adaptive card when search result is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, adaptive-cards, spfx-extension

I created an adaptive card and I would like to only show it when there is data to show.
So in my card I do

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items
.filter("(Status ne 'Completed')")
.orderBy("Created", true)();
```

So when the listitems count > 0
I would like to show the card if possible.